# sort multi-dimensional array by 2 column

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort a 2D array by one of its columns... forexample:

```
$a = array(
    'user4' => array('name' => 'u4', 'payment' => 1000, 'time' => 5000),
    'user2' => array('name' => 'u2', 'payment' => 2000, 'time' => 5000),
    'user3' => array('name' => 'u3', 'payment' => 2000, 'time' => 3000),
);
```

I want to sort it, by `payment` (`DESC`) and `time` (`ASC`).
So sorted array should be like this:

```
$a = array(
    'user3' => array('name' => 'u3', 'payment' => 2000, 'time' => 3000),
    'user2' => array('name' => 'u2', 'payment' => 2000, 'time' => 5000),
    'user4' => array('name' => 'u4', 'payment' => 1000, 'time' => 5000),
);
```

How to do it?
Thanks,

---

I've found the solution:

```
    foreach ($a as $key => $row) {
        $payment[$key]  = $row['payment'];
        $time[$key] = $row['time'];
    }

    array_multisort($payment, SORT_DESC, $time, SORT_ASC, $a);
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Answer (score 2):

You could use `usort`:

```
$arr = array(
    'user4' => array('name' => 'u4', 'payment' => 1000, 'time' => 5000),
    'user2' => array('name' => 'u2', 'payment' => 2000, 'time' => 5000),
    'user3' => array('name' => 'u3', 'payment' => 2000, 'time' => 3000),
);

function mySort($a,$b) {
    if ($a['payment'] == $b['payment']) {
        return $a['time'] - $b['time'];
    } else {
        return $b['payment'] - $a['payment'];
    }
}
usort($arr, 'mySort');
print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => u3
            [payment] => 2000
            [time] => 3000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => u2
            [payment] => 2000
            [time] => 5000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => u4
            [payment] => 1000
            [time] => 5000
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes usort is the answer here.  PHP array_multisort behaves oddly, in my opinion, by forcing you to decompose your naturally formatted table data into separate arrays.

Here is a bare bones solution for multi-column sorting of a table data formatted multidimensional array.

http://pastebin.com/9vCy1jxH

Comment: It's usually recommended to post (relevant) code as part of the suggested solution instead of linking to an external page.